# IE 7 error writing to a document

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using the prototype JavaScript library to read the contents of a text area (which is often the **complete** mark-up for another HTML page), create a new window and then set the new window content to be that same mark-up, like so:

```
var htmlContent = $("msHTML").value;
var win = window.open("preview.cfm", "Preview HTML", "left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1");
win.document.write(htmlContent); //TODO - throwing an error in IE 7 - Error Invalid Argument
win.document.close();
```

This works just fine in Firefox but as mentioned in the comment, it's giving an Illegal Argument exception in IE7.

Can anyone help?

I couldn't find anything in the prototype library that might get around browser differences when setting document content. I know there might be another windowing library built on prototype that might work, but that seems like overkill for this issue I think.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2nd parameter for

```
window.open(url, name, features);
```

**"name" in IE, *MUST NOT* CONTAIN SPACES.** (affects all versions of IE)

```
//works
window.open('page.html', 'mypage', '');

//FAILS in IE
window.open('page.html', 'my page', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove URL and Title from **`window.open()`** - it's a security related issue. You don't need to specify URL anyway since your overwriting window's content on the next line of your code.

This works:

```
var win = window.open('', '', 'left=20,top=20,' +
         'width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1');

win.document.write($("msHTML").value);
```